# Need help on logs moving to S3

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There are different sites configured on my server and I need to move the httpd logs for those sites to S3 in such a way that in S3 the logs should be stored under respective sitename with structure "S3 bucket -> ENVIRONMENT(prd/qa) -> SITE NAME -> log files". Currently i configured as below which directly moves all sites log from /var/log/httpd to s3 with structure "ENVIRONMENT -> INSTANCE ID -> log files". To get instance ID in s3 bucket i used `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`. Below is the current cron

```
*/5 * * * * aws s3 sync /var/log/httpd/ s3://<site-accountname>/prd/`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` --delete
```

Please help to move logs w.r.to sitename

Comment: If the command works from command line directly, use the absolute paths of the executables inside `crontab`